# Client isolation while using Internet Sharing over WiFi

Tags: network, wifi, airport, internet, internet-sharing

I'm using my iMac as a WiFi router, I have a ethernet cable plugged in and sharing internet to my other devices using it's WiFi card.

It creates a WiFi network (infrastructure mode) and I can connect all my devices and use the internet just fine.

My problem is my devices doesn't have access to each other, so for example I can't see my Apple TV from my phone.

Is there any way to turn client isolation off?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to turn off the **Firewall** in your iMac or at least go the Firewall setting and *turn off* "**Enable Stealth mode**" if this is *ON*. You can test first with this and if this don't help, then you can turn off Firewall fully on your iMac. It should work in this way. Let me know how it goes.